# В чем разница между вводным предложением и вставной конструкцией?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Согласно «Полному академическому справочнику», вводные предложения «выделяются запятыми либо, значительно реже, — знаком тире». Например:

> Как выражаются моряки, ветер крепчал.

А в «Тотальном диктанте» было предложение со вставной конструкцией, которую требуется выделять скобками или тире:

> ...а ведь эллины (так называли себя древние греки) стремились тренироваться всё время...

Почему «как выражаются моряки» — это вводное предложение, а «так называли себя древние греки» — вставная конструкция? Какие критерии их разграничения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Вводные предложения**

**Тематика** вводных предложений близка к вводным словам,  а **грамматика и интонация** вписаны в грамматику и интонацию всего предложения, это составная часть предложения.

Вы, я вижу, любите природу. Вам, я думаю, тяжело живётся. И этот голос чудно-новый, ей мнилось, всё ещё звучал. Вечор, ты помнишь, вьюга злилась. Всё это, как рассказывали, ужасно напугало князя. Осмотревшись, я пошёл, как мне казалось, к морю. Мне помогал маляр, или, как он сам себя называл, подрядчик малярных дел. **Постоянной тренировкой занимались древние греки, или, как они  называли себя, эллины.**

**2) Вставные конструкции**

(1) Вставные конструкции содержат дополнительные сообщения, поэтому их **тематика более разнообразна** по сравнению с вводными словами и предложениями. Грамматически и интонационно они выделены из предложения, их **грамматика свободна , не связана с предложением,  обычно не вписывается в его структуру, а интонация имеет вставочный характер второго плана речи** (пониженный тон, измененный темп произношения).

Птенчик упал из гнезда (ветер сильно качал берёзы) и сидел неподвижно. 
Сани резко стукнуло о торчащую из воды сваю (след унесённого моста) и перевернуло. **Дмитрий – так звали моего соседа – был мало заметен в классе.**

Answer (score 3):

Ведущим значением вводных слов и конструкций является значение оценочности – модальной, эмоциональной, экспрессивной.

Как выражаются моряки, ветер крепчал.- оценка источника информации.

Вставные конструкции содержат дополнительные сообщения, попутные сведения. Они разъясняют, комментируют содержание основного предложения в разных отношениях.

...а ведь эллины (так называли себя древние греки) стремились тренироваться всё время...- попутные сведения, разъяснение, кто такие эллины.

Comment: "так называли себя древние греки" ведь тоже является ссылкой на источник информации.

Comment: Источником информации было бы "как говорили древние греки", а "так называли себя древние греки" - самостоятельная информация - объяснение, кто такие эллины, что это именно древние греки и есть, а не просто указание на то, откуда мы это знаем. Это разъяснение содержания предложения, значит, вставная конструкция.